# Spacy Extract named entity relations from trained model

Tags: python, nlp, spacy, named-entity-recognition, named-entity-extraction

How to use Spacy to create a new name entity "cases" - in the context of the number of cases of an infectious disease and then extract the dependencies between this and cardinal number of cases.

For example in the following text 'Of these, 879 cases with 4 deaths were reported for the period 9 October to 5 November 1995.' We would want to extract "879" and "cases"

As per the code for "Training an additional entity type", on Spacy's example documentation page:

https://spacy.io/usage/examples#information-extraction

I used their existing pretrained "en_core_web_sm" english model, to train an addition entity called "CASES" successfully:

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals, print_function

import plac
import random
from pathlib import Path
import spacy
from spacy.util import minibatch, compounding

LABEL = "CASES"

TRAIN_DATA = results_ent2[0:400]

def main(model="en_core_web_sm", new_model_name="cases", output_dir='data3', n_iter=30):
    random.seed(0)
    if model is not None:
        nlp = spacy.load(model)  # load existing spaCy model
        print("Loaded model '%s'" % model)
    else:
        nlp = spacy.blank("en")  # create blank Language class
        print("Created blank 'en' model")
    # Add entity recognizer to model if it's not in the pipeline
    # nlp.create_pipe works for built-ins that are registered with spaCy
    if "ner" not in nlp.pipe_names:
        ner = nlp.create_pipe("ner")
        nlp.add_pipe(ner)
    # otherwise, get it, so we can add labels to it
    else:
        ner = nlp.get_pipe("ner")

    ner.add_label(LABEL)  # add new entity label to entity recognizer
    # Adding extraneous labels shouldn't mess anything up
    if model is None:
        optimizer = nlp.begin_training()
    else:
        optimizer = nlp.resume_training()
    move_names = list(ner.move_names)
    # get names of other pipes to disable them during training
    pipe_exceptions = ["ner", "trf_wordpiecer", "trf_tok2vec"]
    other_pipes = [pipe for pipe in nlp.pipe_names if pipe not in pipe_exceptions]
    with nlp.disable_pipes(*other_pipes):  # only train NER
        sizes = compounding(1.0, 4.0, 1.001)
        # batch up the examples using spaCy's minibatch
        for itn in range(n_iter):
            random.shuffle(TRAIN_DATA)
            batches = minibatch(TRAIN_DATA, size=sizes)
            losses = {}
            for batch in batches:
                texts, annotations = zip(*batch)
                nlp.update(texts, annotations, sgd=optimizer, drop=0.35, losses=losses)
            print("Losses", losses)

    # test the trained model   

    test_text = "There were 100 confirmed cases?"
    doc = nlp(test_text)
    print("Entities in '%s'" % test_text)F
    for ent in doc.ents:
        print(ent.label_, ent.text)

    # save model to output directory
    if output_dir is not None:
        output_dir = Path(output_dir)
        if not output_dir.exists():
            output_dir.mkdir()
        nlp.meta["name"] = new_model_name  # rename model
        nlp.to_disk(output_dir)
        print("Saved model to", output_dir)

        # test the saved model
        print("Loading from", output_dir)
        nlp2 = spacy.load(output_dir)
        # Check the classes have loaded back consistently
        assert nlp2.get_pipe("ner").move_names == move_names
        doc2 = nlp2(test_text)
        for ent in doc2.ents:
            print(ent.label_, ent.text)

main()
```

Testing the output:

```
test_text = 'Of these, 879 cases with 4 deaths were reported for the period 9 October to 5 November 1995. John was infected. It cost $500'
doc = nlp(test_text)
print("Entities in '%s'" % test_text)
for ent in doc.ents:
    print(ent.label_, ent.text)
```

we get a results of

```
Entities in 'Of these, 879 cases with 4 deaths were reported for the period 9 October to 5 November 1995. John was infected. It cost $500'
CARDINAL 879
CASES cases
CARDINAL 4
CARDINAL 9
CARDINAL 5
CARDINAL $500
```

The model has been saved and can correctly identify CASES from the above text.

My goal is to extract the number of cases of a given disease/virus from a news article, and then later also the number of deaths.

I now use this newly created model trying to find the dependencies between CASES and CARDINAL:

Again using Spacy's example

https://spacy.io/usage/examples#new-entity-type

'Training spaCy’s Dependency Parser'

```
import plac
import spacy


TEXTS = [
    "Net income was $9.4 million compared to the prior year of $2.7 million. I have 100,000 cases",
    "Revenue exceeded twelve billion dollars, with a loss of $1b.",
    "Of these, 879 cases with 4 deaths were reported for the period 9 October to 5 November 1995. John was infected. It cost $500"
]


def main(model="data3"):
    nlp = spacy.load(model)
    print("Loaded model '%s'" % model)
    print("Processing %d texts" % len(TEXTS))

    for text in TEXTS:
        doc = nlp(text)
        relations = extract_currency_relations(doc)
        for r1, r2 in relations:
            print("{:<10}\t{}\t{}".format(r1.text, r2.ent_type_, r2.text))


def filter_spans(spans):
    # Filter a sequence of spans so they don't contain overlaps
    # For spaCy 2.1.4+: this function is available as spacy.util.filter_spans()
    get_sort_key = lambda span: (span.end - span.start, -span.start)
    sorted_spans = sorted(spans, key=get_sort_key, reverse=True)
    result = []
    seen_tokens = set()
    for span in sorted_spans:
        # Check for end - 1 here because boundaries are inclusive
        if span.start not in seen_tokens and span.end - 1 not in seen_tokens:
            result.append(span)
        seen_tokens.update(range(span.start, span.end))
    result = sorted(result, key=lambda span: span.start)
    return result


def extract_currency_relations(doc):
    # Merge entities and noun chunks into one token
    spans = list(doc.ents) + list(doc.noun_chunks)
    spans = filter_spans(spans)
    with doc.retokenize() as retokenizer:
        for span in spans:
            retokenizer.merge(span)

    relations = []
    for money in filter(lambda w: w.ent_type_ == "MONEY", doc):
        if money.dep_ in ("attr", "dobj"):
            subject = [w for w in money.head.lefts if w.dep_ == "nsubj"]
            if subject:
                subject = subject[0]
                relations.append((subject, money))
        elif money.dep_ == "pobj" and money.head.dep_ == "prep":
            relations.append((money.head.head, money))
    return relations


main()
```

The output is as follows with no dependency detection. Its as if the model has lost this ability, whilst retained the ability to detect the named entities. Or maybe some kind of setting has been switched off?

```
Loaded model 'data3'
Processing 3 texts
```

If i used the original pretrained model 'en_core_web_sm', the results is:

```
Processing 3 texts
Net income  MONEY   $9.4 million
the prior year  MONEY   $2.7 million
Revenue     MONEY   twelve billion dollars
a loss      MONEY   1b
```

Which is the same as the output for the model on Spacy's example page.

Does anybody know what has happened and why my new model, which used transfer learning on the original Spacy 'en_core_web_sm', is now unable to find the dependencies in this example?

EDIT:

If I use updated trained model, it can detect the new entity "cases" and cardinal "100,000" however it loses the ability to detect money and date.

When i trained the model, I trained it for thousands of sentences, using the base model en_core_web_sm itself to detect all entities and label them so as to avoid the model "forgetting" the old entities.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

According to me if i see the original text

> Net income was $9.4 million compared to the prior year of $2.7
> million. I have 100,000 cases

Spacy pretrained model returns money, date and cardinal as right which are spacy predefined entity labels but when you run your custom model **data_new** you are getting only cases and cardinal as entity label but not money and date.

The reason for this is that when you train the spacy model with your custom data you have only annotated the text corresponding to cardinal and cases and skipped other spacy pretrained labels such as date, money, loc, org and norp. In such scenario catastrophic forgetting is introduced. Please read such concept from this [spacy link](https://explosion.ai/blog/pseudo-rehearsal-catastrophic-forgetting).

My recommendation

- During annotation there should be balanced labels for money, date, cardinal, cases and others that you need. For real time overall balance is not possible but try as much as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Just a way if you want both them add that ner as a pipeline to the sm model after sm's ner .